# Way to call a function within a react return statement

Tags: reactjs

Is their another way to call this function. I'm not sure what kind of function this is. Hopefully someone can fill me in. All i know its a function.

```
{this.getLikes(post.Likes)}
```

without it setting off a

> Maximum update depth exceeded error

```
 getLikes = (count) =>  {
        const myLikes = count.forEach( (like) => like.length);

        this.setState({
            likes: myLikes
        })

    }
    render(){
        const {posts} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                {posts.map((post, i) => (

                    <Paper key={post.id} style={Styles.myPaper}>
                             {this.getLikes(post.Likes)}
                    {/* {...post} prevents us from writing all of the properties out */}
                        <PostItem  
                             myLikes={this.state.likes}                 
                             myTitle={this.state.title} 
                             editChange={this.onChange} 
                             editForm={this.formEditing} 
                             isEditing={this.props.isEditingId === post.id} 
                             removePost={this.removePost} 
                             {...post} 
                        />
                    </Paper>
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't `const myLikes = count.forEach( (like) => like.length);` set `myLikes` to `undefined`, since that's what `forEach` returns? Not sure that's the issue, but that's definitely wrong code

Comment: Can you share the format of `posts`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error Maximum update depth exceeded error happens because you call `setState` in `render()` which shouldn't happen (Look [here](https://itnext.io/react-setstate-usage-and-gotchas-ac10b4e03d60) and [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5591))

You call `{this.getLikes(post.Likes)}` which in turn calls `setState`

If you need to calculate `Likes` during render do something like this

```
 getLikes = (count) =>  {
    const myLikes = // Calculate likes

    return myLikes;

}
```

Your `render()` function may look like this

```
render(){
    const {posts} = this.props;
    return (
        <div>
            {posts.map((post, i) => (

                <Paper key={post.id} style={Styles.myPaper}>

                {/* {...post} prevents us from writing all of the properties out */}
                    <PostItem  
                         myLikes={this.getLikes(post.Likes)}                 
                         myTitle={this.state.title} 
                         editChange={this.onChange} 
                         editForm={this.formEditing} 
                         isEditing={this.props.isEditingId === post.id} 
                         removePost={this.removePost} 
                         {...post} 
                    />
                </Paper>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Please note, that code above not tested, use it as hint. 
Also take note of comment from @Jaromanda X about likes calculation. `forEach` does not return value, so your `getLikes` is incorrect.

Comment: thank you for sharing and giving me a straight forward reason why it didn't work. So pretty much understand now that calling setState within a render will set off a maxium update error. And the function contained setState thats why it gave a maxium update error.